# How do I change the Material UI Toolbar height?

Tags: material-ui

I am new to React and Material UI. I am struggling with how much vertical space the components take up. One thing I would like to do is decrease the height of the toolbar.

I have tried specifying the style:

```
<Toolbar style={{ height: '36px' }}>
```

I have also tried doing it this way:

```
const styles = {
  root: {
    height: 36,
  }
};
<Toolbar className={classes.root} >
```

but neither works. Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: You might need to throw px behind the 36  root: 36px or even root: '36px'

Comment: thanks for that thought... 36px does not compile and '36px' doesn't change the size.

Comment: how about adding padding?

Comment: @sweatpea Height is not changing because in material-ui css min-height is specified as 64px.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I tried changing the Toolbar height before too but it didn't work. 
I end up just setting Toolbar variant to dense which still give me a shorter height Toolbar compared to the regular one.

```
<Toolbar variant="dense">
```

Comment: thank you. this did result in a shorter height Toolbar.

Answer (score 16):

You need to change the min-height to adjust the height, as min-height is specified in material-ui.css as 64px.

```
const styles = {
  customizeToolbar: {
    minHeight: 36
  }
};

<Toolbar className={classes.customizeToolbar} >
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: where do I find the documentation where these types of things are specified?

Comment: Documentation link https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/

Answer (score 8):

To change height of Toolbar globally, configure this in MUI theme:

```
const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
        MuiToolbar: {
            styleOverrides: {
                dense: {
                    height: 32,
                    minHeight: 32
                }
            }
        }
    },
})
```

Then use this theme:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   ...
</ThemeProvider>
```

This way you can tune look of many Mui components in theme, and this will be applied for all elements in the `<ThemeProvider/>` react block.

No css tweaks for individual elements, rather do it correctly in one place by modifying theme.

Comment: This is the best answer just don't forget to add `variant="dense"` to `<Toolbar variant="dense">` component

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way I could get was

```
<Toolbar variant='dense' disableGutters sx={{ minHeight: 20, height: 20 }}>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because the default height is 64px.

To change the height you have to actually change the minHeight property.

To do that, I have used inline styling but it works with other methods too.

```
    const toolbarStyle = {
    minHeight: '80px',
  };
```

Then in your component simply specify the stylename using style attribute

```
<Toolbar style={toolbarStyle}>
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

i too run into a similar issue after some time i put the
min height in AppBar instead of tool bar and it worked here is my code.

```js
return (
    <AppBar position="static" sx={{ height: '70px' }} >
      <Container >
        <Toolbar disableGutters >
        </Toolbar>
      </Container>
    </AppBar>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Assign `minHeight` value:

   ```
   const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
     root: {
       flexGrow: 1,
     },
     toolbar: {
       minHeight: '10px',
       backgroundColor: 'IndianRed'
     }
   }));
   ```
2. ```
   const classes = useStyles();
   ```
3. Simply specify `className` in your component:

   ```
   <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had buttons in my toolbar with default margin. That was preventing the Toolbar to get a height of less than 64px. After setting the button margins to 0 the problem was solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the AppBar's 'top' Css property.
Like so:

```
<AppBar  sx={{ top: -10}}> </AppBar>
```

This solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change the min-height in this way:

```
<Toolbar
   sx={{
      '@media (min-width: 600px)': {
         minHeight: '60px',
      },
   }}
/>
```